# How do I get multiple swiper galleries with thumbs to work on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

```
  var galleryThumbs = new Swiper('.gallery-thumbs', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  slidesPerView: 4,
  loop: true,
  freeMode: true,
  loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
  watchSlidesVisibility: true,
  watchSlidesProgress: true,
});
var galleryTop = new Swiper('.gallery-top', {
  spaceBetween: 10,
  loop: true,
  loopedSlides: 5, //looped slides should be the same
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  thumbs: {
    swiper: galleryThumbs,
  },
});
```

the problem is when i want to use more than two Swiper thumb in one page they will not link properly (galleryThumbs ,galleryTop)
and i think i know the problem is in this part:

```
thumbs: {
swiper: galleryThumbs,
},
```